# WinPE/Wim imaging - Boot issue after imaging, require reboot after to fix MBR

Tags: windows, imaging, wim

I've done lots of googling around until I found an article that did help me fix my issue to some extent... here: [Cannot reboot after applying WIM file](https://serverfault.com/questions/829607/cannot-reboot-after-applying-wim-file)

I've created a 64 bit WinPE image stick using the Microsoft tutorials for mostly Window 10. I have some old windows 7 players that I'm trying to image to Windows 10... we used to use Ghost 64 bit.

I created an menu based batch script to image my players, my first 2 native windows 10 players(PCs) are working fine, but the older windows 7 player is not able to get re-imaged by... what it seems like anything. I can apply the image, but I ALWAYS have boot issues to some extent. By boot issues, either I get a "_" blinking line at the top left side of the screen when windows should be booting, or I get a boot record missing.

I'm using the standard EUFI partition script (yes my player is EUFI based)

```
rem == CreatePartitions-UEFI.txt ==
rem == These commands are used with DiskPart to
rem    create four partitions
rem    for a UEFI/GPT-based PC.
rem    Adjust the partition sizes to fill the drive
rem    as necessary. ==
select disk 0
clean
convert gpt
rem == 1. System partition =========================
create partition efi size=260
rem    ** NOTE: For Advanced Format 4Kn drives,
rem               change this value to size = 260 ** 
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter="S"

rem == 2. Microsoft Reserved (MSR) partition =======
create partition msr size=16

rem == 3. Windows partition ========================
rem ==    a. Create the Windows partition ==========
create partition primary 
rem ==    b. Create space for the recovery tools ===
rem       ** Update this size to match the size of
rem          the recovery tools (winre.wim)
rem          plus some free space.
shrink minimum=650
rem ==    c. Prepare the Windows partition ========= 
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"
assign letter="W"
list volume
exit
```

And I've got the following to try and fix the boot issues (see echo *WARNING* ...)

```
:W10OPSPS
echo imaging c: drive for W10 OPS-PCAEQ-PS
echo.
@echo Find a drive that has a folder titled ApplyImages.
@for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do @if exist %%a:\ApplyImages\ set DriveLetter=%%a
@echo The ApplyImages folder is on drive: %DriveLetter%
@dir %DriveLetter%:\ApplyImages /w
echo.
echo Got the usb drive letter and move forward
echo.

DiskPart /s %DriveLetter%:\CreatePartitions-UEFI.txt

rem == Set high-performance power scheme to speed deployment ==
call powercfg /s 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c

cls

rem == Apply the image to the Windows partition ==
dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:%DriveLetter%:\ApplyImages\%OPS-PCAEQ-PSImageName% /Index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\


rem == Copy boot files to the System partition ==
W:\Windows\System32\bcdboot W:\Windows /s S:


echo *WARNING* this is only needed on this player to fix some odd issue with the hardware imaging portion
DiskPart /s %DriveLetter%:\assignPartitionsAfterImaging(fix).txt
C:\Windows\System32\bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL
bootsect /nt60 sys

echo.
echo the system has been imaged, press any key reboot, take out the USB stick once the reboot has commenced
echo.
echo.
PAUSE
exit
```

here's the other piece that I call during my attempt to fix the issue, just to say I'm issuing the same command to fix the issue in the end:

```
select disk 0
select vol W
assign letter=C
```

Regardless what I put after I apply the image to create the boot records, if I reboot, the I won't be able to boot. BUT, with the exception that I boot BACK into WinPE and run the following:

C:\Windows\System32\bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL

Then I'm all good... and windows boots.

What the hell is going on? How can I automate this portion?

Answer (score 1):

maybe it should be `S:` ?

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f ALL
```